# Microsoft Bot Framework - How to get user data from team channel

Tags: c#, office365, botframework, chatbot, smtp-auth

I have a LUIS Intent in my ChatBot to send an email as a user (code below). At the moment it sends an email as me, to me (but sending from an automation mailbox with permissions to send from everyones mailbox). I want it to read the properties of the user who is interacting with the bot in MS Teams and use that users email address instead?

```
 [LuisIntent("Endpoint_CreateTicket")]
    public async Task EndpointCreateTicketIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                client.Port = 587;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<confidential>", "<confidential>");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                message.From = new MailAddress("Mark.Hawkins-Wood@christie.com");
                message.Subject = "THIS IS THE SUBJECT";
                message.Body = "THIS IS THE BODY";
                message.To.Add("Mark.Hawkins-Wood@christie.com");
                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Microsoft teams does not provide the user's email address to the bot framework.  There is not a way to directly pull it from the context or activity objects.  You are going to have to use something like the graph api to get the email address.

Comment: @JasonSowers perfect, thanks Jason - going to try pull the Name activity and then create a class to resolve that against our DB or GAL

Answer (score 1):

You should have an Intent to extract email. Example you can have an intent called `ExtractEmail` type `Email`

a user can input something like `my email is klex@outlook.com`,

hence your LUIS JSON response returns something like

```
"entities": [
{
  "entity": "klex@outlook.com",
  "type": "Email",
  "startIndex": 18,
  "endIndex": 22,
  "score": 0.9866132
}]
```

From your function try this

```
 using System.Net.Mail;

 try{
  MailAddress mail = new MailAddress(result.entity);
  message.From  = mail;
 }
 catch(Exception){
      //Reply with an error
  }
```

[More information on Intents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-data-extraction)

Comment: Hi John, I guess the only concern of a user input based email address is that a user could just type the email address of anyone else in the org and it would send as that other person.

Comment: But this would just be the LUIS Intent Recognition side of the code wouldn't it? The users intent in this example wouldn't be to tell the bot it's email address, it'd be to request that a ticket is created (by emailing the helpdesk). Then the action of that CreateTicket intent is to email the helpdesk but AS the user, so I need some form of input into the  message.From = new MailAddress("Mark.Hawkins-Wood@christie.com"); section of the code

Comment: retrieve the input from ```LUISResult```, you can bind multiple intents(CreateTicket and EmailRetriver) and loop through the result to access the Email from the user.

Comment: But if the user was to say "my email is ceo@company.com" and actually it's "associate@company.com", that result.entity will just pull the ceo@company.com entity through and use that as the message.From = new MailAddress - there's no auth on that code. And I wanted to avoid the masses of code involved in authentication of the user, and instead just read their email from their Teams profile - as that'll be the channel they're speaking to the bot in

Comment: Sorry, I am answering the originally asked question. That's StackOverflow policy. You can validate email using ```ASP.NET Identity``` familiarize yourself with it.